# Contextual Links not appearing for blocks

Tags: 7, navigation

I have contextual links enabled. I've added

```
print render($action_links);
```

to both my page template and every block template I have but it's always blank. Out of desperation, I set permissions to allow even anonymous users. Still nothing.

I read that Devel might mess with contextual links but I don't have it enabled.

EDIT:

```
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php print render($action_links); ?>
<div style="border: 1px solid #044faa">
   <div style="background: #044faa; color: #fff; padding: 5px 15px; font-size: 16px"><strong><?php echo $block->title; ?></strong></div>

   <div style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center"><?php
   echo preg_replace("/(<)[\/]?[p](>)/is", "", $content);
   ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know `$action_links` is defined as variable for template?

Comment: I didn't see anything that mentioned it having to be defined in the template so I figured it was one of drupal's predefined variables.

Answer (score 2):

Contextual links are printed with:

```
print render($title_suffix);
```

I Have checked it on `block.tpl.php`

See: [Working with contextual links](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual)

I would suggest not to put inline css in your template.
Here working code:

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix" <?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <div <?php print $title_attributes; ?> style="background: #044faa; color: #fff; padding: 5px 15px; font-size: 16px">
     <strong><?php print $title; ?></strong>
   </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div style="border: 1px solid #044faa">
    <div style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center">
      <?php print preg_replace("/(<)[\/]?[p](>)/is", "", $content); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also already added that. The value is always blank.

Comment: Post the code from your template

Comment: code added to the post.

Comment: check my last edit

Comment: I have a feeling that I wrecked something somewhere else in my code because that isn't working, either. I think I'll just cheat because all I need is a link to the configure block area for the selected block and everything I need to do get the needed url is already in the template.

Comment: Have you preprocessed block and unseted some variables?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

In your Chrome or Firefox tools, delete any custom css you've added that could cause them to not show.

I've managed to make this mistake before and also helped someone on /r/drupal who had done the same.

Comment: They're not hidden via css. I've checked the source and they're just not there.

Comment: Ah ok. And if you switch back to garland, do they show?